# Understanding Android Logs Garbage Collector

Tags: android, android-studio, garbage-collection, logcat

I am going through some logs of my application and there are a few things that I do not understand.

Below are the logs:

```
11-29 12:14:01.119 26096 26096 I zygote64: Waiting for a blocking GC Explicit
11-29 12:14:01.994 26096 26106 I zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 771763(93MB) AllocSpace objects, 8(268KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 90MB/114MB, paused 305us total 1.587s
11-29 12:14:01.079 26096 30549 I System.out: PRINTING OBJECTS:
```

So my confusion here is that after the timestamp `11-29 12:14:01.119`, we have two values `26096 26106`, what are those The first one `26096` remains same whereas the second one keeps changing `26106`, `26096`, `30549` and so on.

My second question is, I can see `--------- beginning of main` and duplicate printing of logs. What exactly does `--------- beginning of main` signify and is it the reason the logs are duplicated? I searched for it on SO and other forums but mostly I saw explanations about `--------- beginning of system` and `--------- beginning of crash`.